# For larger arrays - getting back NaN instead of a number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I should write a function that takes in two numbers in form of a string. Takes the first string to the power of the second; return value should be the last digit of the result.

As an example `lastDigit("5", "2")` would return `5`, as 5 to the power of 2 equals 25 and the last digit of that is 5.

It wrote my function like this:

```
   const lastDigit = (str1, str2) => {  
      const [head, ...tail] = Math.pow(parseInt(str1), parseInt(str2)).toString().split("").map(str => parseInt(str)).reverse();
      return head;
      }
```

For smaller sized numbers, the function works properly. But if the numbers get high, somehow it returns

> NaN

How could this be fixed?

Comment: For which input does it give you `NaN`?

Comment: For example for lastDigit("53", "230");

Comment: `Math.pow(53,230).toString() === 'Infinity'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that some numbers, like 53 to the power of 230, are too large for Javascript to deal with: they will give you `Infinity`:

```js
console.log(53 ** 230);
```

Then, in your code, when you try to `parseInt` a *letter* such as `y` in `Infinity`, it will fail and give you `NaN`.

As a workaround, you could multiply the first number together *one at a time*, extract only the ones place by using modulo 10, and repeat as many times as needed:

```js
const lastDigit = (str1, str2) => {
  let num = Number(str1);
  const initial = num;
  const totalIterations = Number(str2);
  for (let i = 1; i < totalIterations; i++) {
    num = (num * initial) % 10;
  }
  return num;
}
console.log(lastDigit("53", "230"));
```

Comment: Oops, you're right, thanks. `i` needs to start at `1`, not `0`, because `num` starts with one number already included

Comment: I've just learned that everything that [looks like a syntax error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**)) actually has a special meaning in JavaScript. That frustrates me even more than PHP.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function _calcPower(){
    var value = document.getElementById('value').value;
    var power = document.getElementById('power').value;
    var result = "Value :"+value+" Power :"+power+" =   "+Math.pow(value,power)+";<br>TO Integer : "+parseInt(Math.pow(value,power))+"<br><br>";
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = document.getElementById('result').innerHTML + result;
    console.log(parseInt(Math.pow(value,power)));
   }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="value" placeholder="Number" />
<input type="text" id="power" placeholder="Power" />
<input type="button" value="Calc" onclick="_calcPower();"/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Some cases Math.pow() will return infinity. So while converting to string to integer it will show NaN. Checkout my code.